# Can I export to .cpo file using OPL?

Tags: modeling, cplex, cp-optimizer

I have a model written in `CPLEX OPL`. Is there a way to export the model to `.cpo` extension?

In Python `docplex` module the syntax is as:

`mdl.export_as_cpo()`

But I could not find an  equivalent command for the `OPL` in the [OPL User's manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/pdf/opl_languser.pdf).

Comment: Does this address your question https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplide/topics/opl_ideref_intell_ed_export_to_cpfile.html ?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks a lot. I think that would work. Probably I have confused ``.cpo`` and ``.ops`` that I could not find it.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone or Mostafa: Since the provided link seems to answer the question, would any of you mind writing that as an answer so that it can be voted/accepted?

Comment: @ EhsanK You can have the honor. To produce my comment above, I jdid a couple of sec of Googling and don't know a damn thing about it - hence I asked whether that link addressed the question, because I wasn;t sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps taken from the [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplide/topics/opl_ideref_intell_ed_export_to_cpfile.html) are:

> - Create a new settings file
> - Change the export format to CPO
> - Add the settings file to the default run configuration
> - Run the run configuration

Thanks to @Mark L. Stone who provided the link.

Answer (score 4):

Other options:

1. Run your model from the command line using `oplrun`. Using option `-d` you can specify to dump your model into a `cpo` file.
2. Specify environment variable `ILC_MODEL_DUMP_FILE`. Before solving the model CP Optimizer tests this variable and if present it dumps the current model into the specified file (the variable can also specify the path to the file). It works for all applications that are using CP Optimizer, not only for OPL.